# JQuery checkbox on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

hope you are all doing well!

So I have been trying to get this thing work. Demo can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/8Q9ut/

Basically, I have a form, consists of multiple rows of checkbox-textbox-textbox-textbox-textbox. Each time the user clicks the checkbox on X-row, the following textboxes will be editable (please see the fiddle).

Now, suddenly the client wants me to create one 'select all' checkbox that will make all the checkboxes checked. I can make it work, but I also need to corresponding textboxes to be editable. how can I get this to work? I thought the code under

```
   $('form').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
```

can already make the textboxes responds based on checkbox event, no?

Thanks for input!

EDIT:
Thanks for all! your solutions ALL work for me, but I chose Ehsan Sajjad's answer just because I only need to add that line to my script and it works like charm. Once again, thanks for your effort!

I have updated the fiddle just in case somebody needs
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q9ut/6/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change your all checkbox change event and do something like this:

```
$('#all').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find('input:text').prop('disabled',!this.checked);

    });
```

it will find all the text boxes and will make them enable and disable on the basis of checkbox checked or unchecked.

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/58BFJ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Set the current status of SelectAll checkbox to rest of the 3 checkbox i.e. if selectall will check others going to be check and vice a versa and finally trigger change event of checkboxes

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/8Q9ut/3/)

```
$('#all').on('click', function () {

    if($(this).is(":checked"))
        $(".clone_me").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
    else
        $(".clone_me").find("input[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);

    $(".clone_me").find("input[type=checkbox]").trigger("change");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q9ut/4/)

Check this,

```
$('#all').on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).closest('.me').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

---

OR better to use a single change function.

**[Single function Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Q9ut/5/)**

```
$('form').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
        console.log('on change');
        var checkbox = $(this);

        //If the selected box is #all

        if(this.id == 'all'){
           $(this).closest('fieldset').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked).closest('.me').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', !$(this).is(':checked'));
         }

        checkbox.closest('.me').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I create this:

**html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Select All</input></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   </tr>

</table>
```

**js**

```
$("#checkAll").on("click", function(){
    $(this).prop("checked") ? $("table").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", true) : $("table").find("input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);       
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xh6v7/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it worked. Try it.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
                console.log('on change');
                var checkbox = $(this);
                /*
                 * If any checkbox is checked, find the nearest input text and enabled user to key in value
                 */
                checkbox.closest('.me').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
            });

            $('#all').on('click', function () {
                var allCheckbox = $(this).is(':checked');
                $.each($('body .me input[type=checkbox]'),function(index,item){
                    $(item).prop('checked', allCheckbox);
                    $(item).closest('.me').find('input[type=text]').prop('disabled', !allCheckbox);
                })
            });

        });
```